# How do I detect clicked coordinates on 3D model in libgdx?

Tags: java, 3d, libgdx

I'm creating simple human body model: 
[image: Human body]

User can rotate the body. I'm using *rotateAround* method from *Camera* class. So, the body can be rotated in different angles. For example: 
[image: Human body rotated 1][image: Human body rotated 2][image: Human body rotated 3]

I would like to know what is the best way to detect which body part has been clicked. How do I check if user clicked chest, head, leg etc.? 
It seems easy in 2D but, unfortunately, I don't know how to program such detection in case of 3D model.

Also, I'm including my code:

```
private PerspectiveCamera camera;
private ModelBatch modelBatch;
private Model model;
private ModelInstance modelInstance;
private Environment environment;
private int dragX, dragY;
private float lightIntensity = 100f;
private PointLight pointLight;

@Override
public void create () {
    camera = new PerspectiveCamera(75, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    camera.position.set(0f, 17.708357f, 13.8000145f);
    camera.lookAt(0f, 7f, 0f);
    camera.near = 0.1f;
    camera.far = 300.0f;

    modelBatch = new ModelBatch();

    UBJsonReader jsonReader = new UBJsonReader();
    G3dModelLoader modelLoader = new G3dModelLoader(jsonReader);

    model = modelLoader.loadModel(Gdx.files.getFileHandle("model.g3db", FileType.Internal));
    modelInstance = new ModelInstance(model);
    modelInstance.transform.rotate(0, 0, 0, 0);
    modelInstance.transform.translate(0, 0, 0);


    environment = new Environment();
    pointLight = new PointLight().set(Color.WHITE, camera.position, lightIntensity);
    environment.add(pointLight);

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);

}

@Override
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    camera.update();

    modelBatch.begin(camera);
    modelBatch.render(modelInstance, environment);
    modelBatch.end();
}

@Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
    float dX = (float)(screenX-dragX)/(float)Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    float dY = (float)(dragY-screenY)/(float)Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    dragX = screenX;
    dragY = screenY;
    Vector3 point = new Vector3(0f, 7f, 0f);
    Vector3 axis = new Vector3(0f, -7f, 0f);
    camera.rotateAround(point, axis, dX * 200f);
    environment.remove(pointLight);
    pointLight = new PointLight().set(Color.WHITE, camera.position, lightIntensity);
    environment.add(pointLight);
    camera.update();
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    dragX = screenX;
    dragY = screenY;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: There's a tutorial here for picking out touched primitive shapes: https://xoppa.github.io/blog/interacting-with-3d-objects/  You can define some spheres for the different parts of the body and detect touch for those spheres.